# GraphQL selection set parsing

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-appsync

I have this GraphQL Selection Set inside my AppSync Lambda Resolver:

```
{
  recommendationId
  items {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I need the selection set inside `items`, which will be heavily nested.

How can I get this output?

```
{
  id
  name
}
```

Context(replaced business object with `Object`):

schema.graphql

```
type Object {
 id: ID!
 name: String!
}

type Query {
 getObjectsById(objectsById: ObjectsByID!): [Object] 
 listRecommendedObjects(personId: ID!): RecommendedObjects
}

input ObjectsByID {
  ids: [ID!]!
}

type RecommendedObjects {
  items: [Object]
  recommendationId: String
}
```

Inside resolver:

```
const buildQuery = (selectionSetGraphQL) =>
  `query MyQuery($objectsById: ObjectsByID!) {
    getObjectsById(objectsById: $objectsById) ${selectionSetGraphQL}
  }`
```

Goal:

Call listRecommendedObjects which will invoke custom lambda that will talk to AWS Personalize to get item IDs.
Then, i want to use the selection set of `Object` to call getObjectsById within that Lambda to get the data of Item IDs from Personalize

Comment: Just iterate through the fields of the selection set until you find an `items` one? Where's the javascript code?

Comment: It's not an object, it's a string.

Comment: Wait, you haven't parsed the query yet? Please post the code that is processing this to provide some context.

Comment: @Bergi I added context to my post. Look at buildQuery, i want to insert the selection set from the query that will be made with listRecommendedObjects

Comment: I recommend to never work with queries as strings. You mention that you are in a resolver (probably the one for `items`?) - you should use the [`resolveInfo` argument](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a) then

Comment: I'm in the resolver for listRecommendedObjects and I need to call getObjectsById inside it to get a list of Objects. The resolver gives me the selectionList for the entire query, I have no way of separating it

Comment: just to clarify ... you know that recommended resolver can return just an array of Object objects with id prop only ... server takes care about the rest ... Object (btw, strange type name) type resolver will(should) fetch the rest of missing Object fields ... (probably you want/need to use "custom JSON type" to hide all nested complexity)

Comment: @AlexandreBoulay ok, that's just one additional level up, the answer is the same.

Comment: @Bergi I do use the info object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-info

Comment: @AlexandreBoulay Please post the full code of the resolver if you have problems with the info object

Comment: @Bergi there's not much insight in the code to be honest. I simply take the info object given to my lambda and invoke buildQuery, I just need to modify selectionSetGraphQL to only include the fields specified below items. Because the signature of the query returns an array of object, I have to conform.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Also in one comment you write "*I simply take the info object*", in another you wrote "*It's not an object, it's a string*". What's the case?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for not being clear. The info object contains selectionSetGraphQL which is a string representation of the selection set, formatted as GraphQL schema definition language (SDL).

Comment: just show the code instead of describing it

Comment: @AlexandreBoulay Then you're probably looking in the wrong property of the info object. It should hold an abstract syntax tree, not just a single string. However I'm not certain which graphql libary you are using, is it a custom one that is not based on `graphql-js`?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know what graphql library AppSync uses under the hood. All I know is the structure of info. In addition to selectionSetGraphQL, it does contain selectionSetList which is basically a list of the selection set, thats the closest to a tree representation that my resolver has access to. If there's a library or tool to convert that list into a graphql formated string, I will be golden.

Comment: Oh, I missed the link to the appsync docs you posted. Yeah, that doesn't look like the `resolveInfo` from graphql-js at all. I suspect [you could still use it - parse, manipulate, stringify](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/language/), but it'll be ugly.

Comment: @Bergi Got it working with graphql-js. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got a sensible solution using `graphql-js`.

I use `parse`, then select what I need, then convert it back to a string with `print`

```js
const { parse, print } = require("graphql/language")

const document = parse('{ id items {id name} }')

const subSet = document
  .definitions[0]
  .selectionSet
  .selections
  .find(elem => elem.name.value == 'items')

print(subSet) // => `items {id name}`
```